# Batch file that copy itself to folders in current directory?

Tags: file, batch-file, copy

The Scenario is this.

I have a batch file in I:\test.bat
In I drive, there are 3 folders. like this.

```
I:\folder1
I:\folder2
I:\folder2\folder3
```

Assume that I don't know the name of folder1, folder2, and folder3
So, How can I make a batch file that knows the folders in the current path and then copy it with the same name?

I want to have this.

```
I:\folder1\test.bat
I:\folder2\test.bat
I:\folder2\folder3\test.bat
```

How do you make that happen?

Comment: Why would you need a batch file for every folder?

Answer (score 2):

try this, look at the output and remove the `echo`, if it is OK:

```
@echo off
cd /d I:\
for /r /d %%i in (folder?) do echo copy "%~f0" "%%i"
```

This expands the batch file name to the full path+file name: `%~f0`.

Answer (score 0):

from a commandline this works:

```
for /d %a in (*) do copy test.bat "%a"
```

use double %%a if you plan this for a batch file

In a batch file to copy itself in all subfolders

```
@echo off 
for /d %%a in (*) do copy "%~n0%~x0" "%%a"
```

From the `help for` command:

```
FOR /D %variable IN (set) DO command [command-parameters]

    If set contains wildcards, then specifies to match against directory
    names instead of file names.
```

From the `help call` command:

```
 Substitution of batch parameters (%n) has been enhanced.  You can
 now use the following optional syntax:

     %~n1        - expands %1 to a file name only
     %~x1        - expands %1 to a file extension only
```

Comment: Better to use `%~f0` instead of `%~n0%~x0` so as to get the full path to the executing batch file. When you do us the `n` and `x` modifiers,  you can simply combine them as `%~nx0`